# Inconsistent "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument" error

Tags: python

The `add_to_log` function defined in the following code is called thousands of times during the execution of a script:

```py
LOGFILENAME = 'N:\\Tools\\DelOldTempSave.log'

def add_to_log(text):
    with open(LOGFILENAME, 'a') as logfile:
        now = str(datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))
        logfile.write(now + ' ' + text + '\n')
        print(now + ' ' + text)
```

It usually works as expected, but once in a while it crashes with:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'N:\\Tools\\DelOldTempSave.log'
```

I tested it 3 times, it crashed after 3200, 1700 and 10200 calls.

I think I can use a `try` / `except` block and give it another try when it fails, maybe after a `time.sleep(0.1)`, but it's a little scary!

The `open` function is used also on other parts of the script. Does it mean that I need to use a `try` / `except` block wherever it is called?

Also, the `open` function is used on other scripts. Does it mean that I need to use a `try` / `except` block wherever it is called on whatever script?

And I can't trust python when writing to a text file?

**EDIT**

This version works without errors:

```py
import os, time, datetime

LOGFILENAME = 'N:\\Tools\\text.log'
NROWS = 30000


def add_to_log(text):
    try:
        with open(LOGFILENAME, 'a') as logfile:
            now = str(datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))
            logfile.write(now + ' ' + text + '\n')
            print(now + ' ' + text)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    except OSError as e:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        add_to_log(f'Crash: {e}')
        add_to_log(text)


if os.path.exists(LOGFILENAME):
    os.unlink(LOGFILENAME)

for n in range(NROWS):
    add_to_log(str(n))
```

There are still three problems with this:

1. Decreasing the duration in `time.sleep(0.1)` increases the chances of error, so I'm not 100% sure 0.1 is a long enough duration to ensure no error
2. How do I know that this problem is restricted to this function and it will not spread to other functions that call `open`
3. Adding a 0.1 second pause on a function that is called 30000 times, adds 3000 seconds to the duration of the script

Note: `N:` is a network drive. I want the log file to be visible to all computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I can't trust python when writing to a text file?

> Yes, it is a network drive. I want the log file to be visible to all computers.

It sounds more like you can't trust your network file system. Reliably appending to a file would require a (distributed network) lock to be taken out on the file, anyway, and if that works, it could be slow.

Rather than opening and closing a single log file every time you need to write something, I'd recommend generating a single random log file name at the start of your program, and writing there:

```
import secrets

LOGFILENAME = f'N:/Tools/text.{secrets.token_urlsafe(8)}.log'
LOGFILE = open(LOGFILENAME, "w")  # will be closed when the program ends


def add_to_log(text):
    now = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()
    LOGFILE.write(f'{now} {text}\n')
    LOGFILE.flush()  # if you want to ensure the text is written
    print(f'{now} {text}')
```

If you need a single file later on, you can just concatenate all of those files together and `sort` them.

Comment: I tested the same in VBA and it fails once every 30000~ attempts vs Python once every 5000~. The higher reliability in VBA may be due to the fact that VBA is slower (either it gives more time to the OS to manage the file opening or VBA itself does a few more checks).
This seems to confirm that the problem is with the network drive.
This is also telling me that I need to add a `try` / `except` block around the single `open` at the beginning of the script.